# How do I replace a string between 2 certain tags

Tags: powershell, tags

I have a text file with the following text in:

```
<ServerAddress>.</ServerAddress>
<ServerDatabase>test</ServerDatabase>
<ServerUsername>jimmy</ServerUsername>
```

I want to be able to replace the "." with a `read-host` entered piece of text.
For example change it from `<ServerAddress>.</ServerAddress>` to

```
<ServerAddress>server1</ServerAddress>
```

The code I have to far works... but it replaces everything in the file to the same string over and over, so in the example from above, it would have replaced everything with `<ServerAddress>server1</ServerAddress>`

Here is what I have so far:

```
pushd "C:\PSF\Move to V6\DTT Files"
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.dtt -rec
$servername = Read-Host 'What the server name?'
$regex='(m?)>[^<]+<'
foreach ($file in $configFiles)

{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { "<ServerAddress>.</ServerAddress>" -replace $regex, ">$servername<" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex to replace XML content. Instead, load the file as XML, select the node and set the values:

Example:

```
[xml]$xml =
@'
<root>
    <ServerAddress>.</ServerAddress>
    <ServerDatabase>test</ServerDatabase>
    <ServerUsername>jimmy</ServerUsername>
</root>
'@

$xml.DocumentElement.ServerAddress = 'newServer'
$xml.Save('yourLocation')
```